# How to monitor nginix using ganglia

Tags: ganglia

I have installed Ganglia 3.7.2 on RHEL 6.6 server. I have setup cluster to monitor db server its working fine. But now i want setup monitoring for nginx server. Please let me know if any one monitoring nginx server with ganglia.

I have added below given things on client

```
module {     
    name = "python_module"    
    path = "modpython.so"      
    params = "/etc/ganglia/python_modules"     
}    
include ("/etc/ganglia/python_modules/*.pyconf")
```

But when i restart gmond service it gave me error :

> [root@12-105-IDC ganglia]# /etc/init.d/gmond start
>   Starting GANGLIA gmond: loaded module: core_metrics
>   loaded module: cpu_module
>   loaded module: disk_module
>   loaded module: load_module
>   loaded module: mem_module
>   loaded module: net_module
>   loaded module: proc_module
>   loaded module: sys_module
>   loaded module: python_module
>   loaded module: python_module
>   /bin/bash: line 1: 14675 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
>   /usr/sbin/gmond
>   [FAILED]

Comment: is it possible to monitor nginix by using ganglia ????

Comment: reformated the code for better readability and shorter error log (removed blank lines).